# An Issue while connecting WebSocket (socketo.me) to the hosted server

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, ratchet, phpwebsocket

As I tried to run the chat app from localhost connected to MySQL database which had been coded with PHP via WebSocket it was successful.

Also when I tried to run 
from the PuTTY terminal logged into SSH credentials, it was displaying as Server Started with the port# 8383

```
somelabz@bh-ht-3 [~/public_html/chatroom-php-mysql/bin]# php server.php
Server Started.somelabz@bh-ht-3 [~/public_html/chatroom-php-mysql/bin]# php server.php
Server Started.
```

The server starts with any of the port# except with 8080. So as I have decided to open the port with 8383, as a result, it had started successfully

***With the port 8080, error_log was getting generated as***

```
[07-Oct-2018 06:11:02 Etc/GMT] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Failed to listen on "tcp://0.0.0.0:8080": Address already in use in /home/somelabz/public_html/chatroom-php-mysql/vendor/react/socket/src/TcpServer.php:164
Stack trace:
#0 /home/somelabz/public_html/chatroom-php-mysql/vendor/react/socket/src/Server.php(36): React\Socket\TcpServer->__construct('tcp://0.0.0.0:8...', Object(React\EventLoop\StreamSelectLoop), Array)
#1 /home/somelabz/public_html/chatroom-php-mysql/vendor/cboden/ratchet/src/Ratchet/Server/IoServer.php(59): React\Socket\Server->__construct('0.0.0.0:8080', Object(React\EventLoop\StreamSelectLoop))
#2 /home/somelabz/public_html/chatroom-php-mysql/bin/server.php(15): Ratchet\Server\IoServer::factory(Object(Ratchet\Http\HttpServer), 8080)
#3 {main}
  thrown in /home/somelabz/public_html/chatroom-php-mysql/vendor/react/socket/src/TcpServer.php on line 164
```

**server.php**

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
   new HttpServer(
     new WsServer(
          new Chat()
    )
   ),
   8383
);
$server->run();
```

**chatroom.php**

```
// For other computers to connect, you will probably need to change this to your LAN IP or external IP,
// alternatively use: gethostbyaddr(gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
// $Server->wsStartServer($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'], 9300);
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8383');
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8383');
            conn.onopen = function(e) {
                console.log("Connection established!");
            };

    ...
</script>
```

Checking the console information from the browser I used to get the following logs when I tried to switch/change the domain name as well as port# playing with permutations & combinations from the file `chatroom.php` and `server.php`

> var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8383');
>   var conn = new
>   WebSocket('ws://192.197.161.61/~somelabz:8383');
>   var conn = new
>   WebSocket('ws://somelabz.ml/chatroom-php-mysql:8383');
>   var conn = new
>   WebSocket('ws://somelabz.ml:8383/');
>   var conn = new
>   WebSocket('ws://192.197.161.61:8383/');

I used to get the following errors as follows:

> chatroom.php:73 WebSocket connection to 'ws://somelabz.ml:8383/'
>   failed: Error in connection establishment:
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
>
> chatroom.php:73 WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://192.197.161.61/~somelabz:8383' failed: Error during WebSocket
>   handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
>
> WebSocket connection to 'ws://somelabz.ml/chatroom-php-mysql:8383'
>   failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code:
>   404
>
> WebSocket connection to 'ws://somelabz.ml:8383/' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
>
> WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.197.161.61:8383/' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

---

**How am I suppose to resolve/overcome while connecting it from the `WebSocket`  especially from the hosted server with the domain name such as `http://somelabz.ml/chatroom-php-mysql`**

> var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8383');

This was the composer files generated after executing and adding src folder `$composer require cboden/ratchet`

**composer.json(On Server)**

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyApp\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.1"
    }
}
```

**composer.json(On localhost)**

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyApp\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### The Final Conclusion is

You'll never have any other options to run any services on the Re-seller's Account server even with `Node.js`

**Solutions lies either in changing our coding or upgrading/buying server:**

1. **AJAX Long Pooling**
2. **Dedicated hosting service**
3. **Virtual private server(VPS)**

**Firstly,**

Well, Bluehost site writes:

> "We block access to certain ports to help avoid having security holes
>   in the firewall... Purchasing a dedicated IP will allow us to grant
>   you access to the ports you will need to run your specific services
>   on.".

Since the BlueHost server is blocking incoming requests to the socket on specific ports is because they don`t allow WebSocket on shared hosting. 

The only way to get a similar result would be to use AJAX Long Pooling or
we need an upgrade to a Virtual Server to run your own services.

> we are not supposed to run scripts like phpwebsocket within a web
>   service (it is a server itself). This confuses a lot of people since
>   PHP is typically  used for scripting web pages, not for coding daemons

I say this because I had mentioned running the script within Xampp, and referred to the hosting service as 'Bluehost'.
If this is the case we need to upgrade to a virtual server package so that you can run your own services.

There are up to 65,535 ports. The web server cannot use ports below 1024 as listening sockets, 
because on most systems ports below that require root privileges. 
No sane provider would run a web server as root. This affects all Linux servers. 
That's why it works on the Xampp with port# 443 & 80 in httpd-ssl.conf & httpd.conf respectively. We need to have dedicated server. At least virtual.

**Secondly,**

Before listening on a socket I must first bind it to an address.
Binding to an address defines exactly which interface should have that server port open. 
Binding to 0.0.0.0 is a special case when you want to listen to all IP addresses know to the interface. 
Binding specifically to 127.0.0.1 should make the server port visible only to code that can connect to the localhost (e.g. local processes).
Binding can be used to only accept local connections. If you have multiple IP addresses you can also have different servers listening on the 
same port but on different IP's

---

**Update:**

In my case, server was not supporting to run web services. It's possible for some one to go & opt for Cloud services like GCP, Amazon, Heroku and rest so on. But it definitely puts some overhead cost associated with it, incase if you are trying to run these project over longer period of time